# Is there documentation on Craft.AdminTable?

Tags: plugin-development

My plugin has a many-to-many relationship and I would like to build a "associate" form with search/sort, and an icon to save selected record in the assoication table.   It would be great to leverage the Craft AdminTable feature, but I need to extend the 'deleteIcon' action.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

None of Craft's JavaScript is documented.  Your best bet is going to be to look at the source itself in `craft/app/resources/js`.

Comment: Yea, been doing that.  makes my eyes hurt ;-)    I find that the 'tools' class is very close to what I need, so I am reading 'assetindex' as an example.